# How can I prevent my SQL subquery from caching data in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to insert test data to test [postgresql partionning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-partitioning.html), using Postgresql 11.

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE measurement (
    city_id         int not null,
    logdate         date not null,
    peaktemp        int,
    unitsales       int
);
```

Here is my statement to insert test data:

```
explain insert into measurement(
  city_id,
  logdate,
  peaktemp,
  unitsales
)
select
  ( 
    select (random() * 10000)::int + (generator*0) as city_id 
  ),
  ( 
    select 
        * 
    from 
        (select * from generate_series('2006-01-01'::timestamp,
                                       '2006-12-31'::timestamp,
                                       '1 day')) as rng
    order by
        random()
    limit 1
  ) as logdate,
  ( 
    select (random() * 10000)::int + (generator*0) as peaktemp 
  ),
  ( 
    select (random() * 10000)::int + (generator*0) as unitsales 
  )
from generate_series(1, 1000) as generator
```

The problem is: when I run this statement, the select subquery which generates the field `logdate` seems to be cached and the table `measurement` contains a single value for the field `logdate`.

So, if I run the following query:

```
select distinct(logdate)
from measurement
```

I only get a single value:
`2006-02-10`

How can I prevent the caching side-effect?

Comment: Your query seems to be gratuitously complicated, but if you don't want to rearrange it, you could just `order by random()+generator` to force the subselect to re-evaluated each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've observed, the `ORDER BY` is calculated once for the sub-query, such that for each row that's generated in your outer query, the selected row is going to be the same.  As such, you won't be able to use sub-selects and `ORDER BY` to achieve what you're aiming for, even though you call `random()`.

Try this:

```
SELECT
  (random() * 10000)::int AS city_id,
  '2006-01-01'::timestamp + random() * ('2006-12-31'::timestamp - '2006-01-01'::timestamp) AS logdate,
  (random() * 10000)::int AS peaktemp,
  (random() * 10000)::int AS unitsales
FROM
generate_series(1,1000);
```

I'm not sure what your requirements are, but I don't think you need to have 1) a bunch of sub-selects or 2) all the references to `generator*0`, so I've removed them too.

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Concerning 1) and 2), I was following a generate_series guide.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
select
  (random() * 10000)::int as city_id,
  (
    '2006-01-01'::timestamptz
    +random()*(
      ('2006-01-01'::timestamptz+'1 year'::interval)
      -'2006-01-01'::timestamptz
    )
  ) as logdate,
  (random() * 10000)::int as peaktemp,
  (random() * 10000)::int as unitsales
from generate_series(1, 1000) as generator;
```

Although I'm confused whether you want a timestamptz (you definitely don't want timestamp, without timezone, as this type is evil) or a date in logdate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I use Timestamp just to test stuff, but I probably wont use it in production code.